# Confusion about euler path,trail,circuit?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

What's the difference between a euler trail, path,circuit,cycle  and a regular trail,path,circuit,cycle since edges cannot repeat for all of them anyway?
And can vertices be repeated in a euler path?
Clarification will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions taken according to Diestel's text Graph Theory:

- A **path** is a nonempty graph $P=(V,E)$ with $V=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k\}$, $E=\{x_0x_1,x_1x_2,x_2x_3,\dots,x_{k-1}x_k\}$ where all $x_i$ are distinct.  The path's length is the number of edges, $k$.
- A **cycle** is a path of length $k\geq 2$ along with an additional edge included between $x_0$ and $x_k$.  The cycle's length is the number of edges (*including this new one*).
- A **circuit** is essentially a cycle with the slightly different nuance that we are specifically referring to the edge-set as an element of the edge space when viewing this through the lens of linear algebra, not the graph itself.
- A **walk** (*also called a trail*) is a nonempty alternating sequence of vertices and edges $v_0e_0v_1e_2v_2e_2\dots e_{k-1}v_k$ where $e_i$ is an edge between $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ for all $i<k$.  A walk is **closed** if $v_0=v_k$.

Note that a walk/trail may repeat vertices and edges while a path may not repeat vertices (*and hence cannot repeat edges either*) and neither can a cycle (*not counting starting and ending vertices*).  Also note that circuits often refer to the same thing as cycles in common practice as not everyone follows strict naming conventions.

---

- A graph is called **Eulerian** if it there exists an **Eulerian Tour**, a closed walk which visits every edge exactly once.
- A graph is called **semi-eulerian** if it has an **Eulerian Walk**, a walk which visits every edge exactly once, but not such a closed walk.

You will often see people refer to Eulerian cycles, Eulerian circuits, Eulerian paths, and Eulerian trials.  Often times, either they have defined these terms differently, or they simply mean Eulerian Tours and Eulerian Walks respectively while using an incorrect word.  (*That is to say, an "Eulerian Cycle" is not necessarily a "cycle" in that we allow vertices to repeat*)

---

In recap: Euler <**insert object here**> are like regular <**insert object here**> except they must use **every** available edge in the entire graph (*and could possibly repeat vertices which is otherwise not allowed depending on strictness of naming conventions followed by that person*).  It is not strong enough to simply not repeat edges, but rather all edges in the graph must be used.

Comment: I have a related question. A graph may have a Euler Trail or not. It may have a Euler cycle or not. However, is it the case that they may have both? Or neither?

Comment: @DeanP a cycle is just a special type of trail.  A graph with a Euler cycle necessarily also has a Euler trail, the cycle being that trail.  A graph is able to have a trail while not having a cycle.  For trivial example, a path graph.  A graph is able to have neither, for trivial example a disjoint union of cycles.